# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) when calling ManagedObjectContext save:&error]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

Sorry to be asking what appears to be the same question as posted before, however, I have been through all of the questions so far to no avail.

Under certain circumstances, I am seeing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash - very reproducibly.

The app is a basic messaging app I'm working on to better understand Objective C and iOS programming.

I have two tableViews, one containing the list of people you're talking to, and another view that contains all of the messages for the conversation.  If I initialize conversations into CoreData during app launch, I have no problems.

When I start a new conversation from an empty table view, everything seems to be OK.  I can talk to the person back and forth.  When I back out into the primary messages list, again I see the new thread in the table view.  The problem occurs when I re-enter the thread and try to add more messages to the conversation - CRASH.  When I re-launch the app, I can continue without any problems.  It's only this first one that causes issues.  I feel like it's something to do with the context being created in a subview, and being released when I return to the parent view.

I'm using a singleton NSManagedObjectContext currently initialized as such (AppDelegate.m):

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Managed Object Context Doesn't exist yet - creating it!");
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

and also in AppDelegate.m, I have a save method:

```
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"[APPDELEGATE] Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Wherever I do any fetchedResultsController work in ViewDidLoad, I call a utility class like this

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext*) getContextFromDelegate{
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [app managedObjectContext];

    return context;
}
```

And finally, the stacktrace for the crash:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x9dba, 0x371a3f66 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 6, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x77656962)
    frame #0: 0x371a3f66 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 6
    frame #1: 0x29724370 CoreData`__77-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 1832
    frame #2: 0x296b11a0 CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 180
    frame #3: 0x296b1342 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 190
    frame #4: 0x29650832 CoreData`-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 114
    frame #5: 0x298ddf14 CoreFoundation`__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    frame #6: 0x29838e4c CoreFoundation`_CFXNotificationPost + 1800
    frame #7: 0x2a56dec0 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 76
    frame #8: 0x296507a2 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 78
    frame #9: 0x2965073a CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] + 298
    frame #10: 0x2964ecda CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2434
    frame #11: 0x2964d976 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 222
  * frame #12: 0x000f4730 wormhole`__26-[AppDelegate saveContext]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=<unavailable>) + 112 at AppDelegate.m:605
    frame #13: 0x296b11a0 CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 180
    frame #14: 0x296b1342 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 190
    frame #15: 0x000f46ac wormhole`-[AppDelegate saveContext](self=0x1555dde0, _cmd=0x00196329) + 180 at AppDelegate.m:603
    frame #16: 0x0010bfae wormhole`+[ClientUtilities saveContext](self=0x001cc580, _cmd=0x00196329) + 162 at ClientUtilities.m:372
    frame #17: 0x000f8966 wormhole`+[CoreDataUtils saveMessage::](self=0x001cc418, _cmd=0x001935ff, new_msg=0x169964e0, personRecord=0x16abc080) + 750 at CoreDataUtils.m:73
    frame #18: 0x000bc2be wormhole`-[MessagesViewController pressSendButton:](self=0x16ae4670, _cmd=0x001930d0, sender=0x16adf1d0) + 950 at MessagesViewController.m:737
    frame #19: 0x2cdfe196 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 70
    frame #20: 0x2cdfe138 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
    frame #21: 0x2cde8d1c UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 584
    frame #22: 0x2cdfdb68 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 584
    frame #23: 0x2cdfd842 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 522
    frame #24: 0x2cdf7150 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 540
    frame #25: 0x2cdcd8c4 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
    frame #26: 0x2d041372 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 13874
    frame #27: 0x2cdcc306 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1294
    frame #28: 0x298ebfd6 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
    frame #29: 0x298eb3ea CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 222
    frame #30: 0x298e9a68 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 768
    frame #31: 0x29836b30 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    frame #32: 0x29836942 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #33: 0x30c16050 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 136
    frame #34: 0x2ce2c6f0 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1440
    frame #35: 0x000f830c wormhole`main(argc=1, argv=0x003c6aec) + 108 at main.m:14
```

The last log line that gets called is a "didChangeObject: Update" in the parent view controller before the crash.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Looks like wormhole is causing the problem...

Comment: What does [self persistentStoreCoordinator] look like? Is there any chance you are getting a managedObjectContext without a coordinator? Also, are you calling your saveContext helper method on the main thread?